# Points to line in ArcMap with colours

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I have points table in ArcMap. I would like to make a points to line based upon a column "Element" and make a color scheme. I made it in ArcMap , see figure. The first green line with name element "II" is made using points 1 to 5 and second blue line "III" using points 6 to 15. I would like to start the blue line right at the edge of green line and so on. I do not want any gap in between.

How should I do this?

Should I need to modify points table in some way or can do it in line table or under symbology?

Any suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you would need to duplicate the start and end points for each colour bracket. For example, the final point in your green line "II", should also be the first point in your blue line "III".